# Error exception handling of Java FX input field, ensure that field only accepts positive integers

Tags: java

At the moment my error exception handling returns an error if the field is empty - how can I expand this to include all characters which are not positive integers?

```
Button hdButton=new Button();
hdButton.setText("Save");
hdButton.setOnAction(e -> 
    {
        if(memoryField.getText().isEmpty())
        {
            dsdisplay2.setText("ERROR: You must enter a positive number in order to set the 
            memory\n");
        }
        else
        {
            s1.setHardDisk(Integer.parseInt(hardDisk.getText()));
            dsdisplay2.setText("The Hard Disk size for your PC has been set to: " + s1.getMemory());

        }
```

Comment: Use parseUnsignedInt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap `Integer.parseInt()` in a `try` block and `catch` the `NumberFormatException`.

```
try {
    int size = Integer.parseInt(hardDisk.getText());
    s1.setHardDisk(size);
    dsdisplay2.setText("The Hard Disk size for your PC has been set to: " + s1.getMemory());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    dsdisplay2.setText("ERROR: You must enter a positive number in order to set the memory\n");
}
```

This way, you won't need to validate the input before setting `s1.setHardDisk` as the `Integer.parseInt` will throw an exception if the input is malformed.

Comment: Thanks for the information - how could I expand this to include input range? For example - the input has to be an integer > 0

Comment: @AlexanderNorrington You can put an `if ` after `int size=...` and check the integer if it's positive set the `s1.setHardDisk(size)`, otherwise show an error.